# MongoDB updating Data in a query

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, find

I've this string in my mongo DB:

```
{"data":{"data":"abc"},"user":"xyz"}
```

But i need this.

```
{"data":abc","user":"xyz"}
```

But my data is binary formatted

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly?

```
> db.a.save({"data":{"data":"abc"},"user":"xyz"})
> db.a.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d679982582b20ad127ce98"), "data" : { "data" : "abc" }, "user" : "xyz" }
> db.a.aggregate({$project:{data:'$data.data', user:1}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51d679982582b20ad127ce98"),
            "data" : "abc",
            "user" : "xyz"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```